# Как через WIN_API сделать виртуальное хранилище и синхронизировать с сервером?

Tags: windows, explorer, cloud-driver

Стоит задача: создать файловое хранилище, очень похожее на популярные сервисы:

- DropBox
- Yandex Cloud
- Google Cloud
- И так далее

---

Не могу найти информацию/библиотеки для работы с `Windows Explorer` (`WIN_API`).

Не понимаю, каким образом сервисы облачного хранилища:

- могут ниже иконки файла отобрать свою (иконка сообщает статус: синхронизация, синхронизировано, и так далее).
- могут некоторые файлы и папки отображать без интернета (скачанные заранее).
- и многое другое.

---

Предлагать библиотеки желательно для языков:

- C#
- Python

Но, так же, буду благодарен за библиотеки реализованные на других языках.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/cloud-files-api-portal